# find how many requests are on queue in thread safe spring controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using a spring controller which returns a string from a threadsafe method.
so i have made the controller also thread safe.
I want to know how many request are there in queue simultaneously which are calling to the spring controller

Comment: When you say you "made the controller also threadsafe", what do you mean? Do you mean you just made all the methods `synchronized`? That's a very poor idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion how you can solve your issue.

Imagine you have this `@Controller`:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private IMyService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/myPathName", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {

        // you synchronized call
        service.callSynchronized(request, model); 

        return "someJsp";
    }

    // +edit
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/queueStatus", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(HttpServletRequest request) {

        // 
        return "inQueue: " + request.getAttribute("inQueue");
    }
}
```

Now you can define an `interceptor` and count the requests before and after execution:

```
public class RequestsInWorkInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private static final Logger _logger  = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestsInWorkInterceptor.class);
    private final AtomicLong counter     = new AtomicLong();

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        String methodURI = request.getRequestURI();
        long current;
        if("myPathName".equals(methodURI){
            current = counter.incrementAndGet();
            _logger.debug("current {} clients in a queue", current);
        } else {
            current = counter.get(); // just get, no increment
        }

        // +edit: put the count in the request so you can get it in you controller
        request.setAttribute("inQueue", current);
        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        String methodURI = request.getRequestURI();
        if("myPathName".equals(methodURI){
            counter.decrementAndGet();
        }
        super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Abhilash no problem ;)

Comment: can you please suggest any external way to find out the no of request in the queue, like without using interceptor and by using an external method to check the no of requests in the queue.

Comment: @Abhilash what exactly do you mean?

Comment: like some external methods which will be only use to check how many request are on the queue in the controller

Comment: thnks @dit its woking fine

Comment: this adds the inqueue for each request. how can we see how many requests are currently in the queue?

Answer (score 0):

You can get information about the number of active requests using Jetty's StatisticsHandler and JMX.

If you're using Jetty as an embedded container (the recommended approach), you can use an EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer to set this up:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        ((JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container)
                .addServerCustomizers(new JettyServerCustomizer() {

            @Override
            public void customize(Server server) {
                MBeanContainer mbContainer = new MBeanContainer(
                        ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer());
                server.addEventListener(mbContainer);
                server.addBean(mbContainer);

                StatisticsHandler statisticsHandler = new   StatisticsHandler();
                statisticsHandler.setHandler(server.getHandler());
                server.setHandler(statisticsHandler);
            }
        });
    }

    };
    }
```

You'll need to add a dependency on org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx to get access to MBeanContainer.

2. You can try with spring boot actuator. On endpoint /metrics you should have field "httpsessions.active"
3. public class RequesInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    private static Object lock = new Object();
    private static int count =  0

   @Override
   public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response, Object handler) throws ServletException {
       sinchronize(lock){
                   count++;
               }
    }

   }